# Image style scale and crop not formatting right

Tags: 7, media

I had a scale and crop image style created, but I had to move it to code.  So, to re-create it, my code is:

```
function mymodule_image_default_styles() {
    $styles = array();

    $styles['mymodule_thumb'] = array(
        'label' => 'MyModule Thumbnail',
        'effects' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'image_scale_and_crop',
                'data' => array(
                    'width' => 210,
                    'height' => 210

                ),
            )
        ),
        'name' => 'mymodule_thumb',
        'storage' => IMAGE_STORAGE_NORMAL

    );

    return $styles;
}
```

It's scaling to the 210px width, but it doesn't seem to be cropping right.

Am I missing something?  Before this, I tried separate scale and crop effects, but got the same result.

EDIT: If it matters, I'm calling image_style_url() and passing the style.

[image: Works when setting through UI]

[image: Doesn't work with my code]

Comment: Why not use Features to export it then copy the code?

Comment: I already have a ton of stuff set up for ctools export.  It's only 3 styles, so I was hoping to just throw them into the style hook.

Comment: What I meant is, you can export it into a dummy feature, then just cut and paste the `hook_image_default_styles` code it generated in the `featurename.features.inc` file into your own module. And then delete that dummy feature. But see my answer below if you want to have a manual stab at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the [`hook_image_defaults_styles`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.api.php/function/hook_image_default_styles/7) API page might be a bit out of date?

The features exported hook_image_default_styles code is slightly different on my drupal. Maybe this will help:

```
function hook_image_default_styles() {
  $styles = array();

  // Exported image style: learning_sessions_image.
  $styles['learning_sessions_image'] = array(
    'name' => 'learning_sessions_image',
    'effects' => array(
      7 => array(
        'label' => 'Scale and crop',
        'help' => 'Scale and crop will maintain the aspect-ratio of the original image, then crop the larger dimension. This is most useful for creating perfectly square thumbnails without stretching the image.',
        'effect callback' => 'image_scale_and_crop_effect',
        'dimensions callback' => 'image_resize_dimensions',
        'form callback' => 'image_resize_form',
        'summary theme' => 'image_resize_summary',
        'module' => 'image',
        'name' => 'image_scale_and_crop',
        'data' => array(
          'width' => 963,
          'height' => 270,
        ),
        'weight' => 1,
      ),
    ),
    'label' => 'learning_sessions_image',
  );
  return $styles;
}
```

What you're missing is the `effect callback` and `dimensions callback` which are the essential parts afaik. I'm not sure about the significance of the array index under `effects`, or the `form callback` and `summary theme`. Hope this helps.

Comment: That works.  I actually haven't used features yet, so I will definitely be using it for exporting.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this code. Try using this

```
function mymodule_image_default_styles() {
  $styles = array();

  $styles['mymodule_thumb'] = array(
    'label' => 'MyModule Thumbnail',
    'effects' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'image_scale',
        'data' => array(
          'width' => 200,
          'upscale' => 1,
          'height' => 200,
        ),
        'weight' => 0,
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'image_crop',
        'data' => array(
          'width' => 210,
          'height' => 210
        ),
      )
    ),
    'name' => 'mymodule_thumb',
    'storage' => IMAGE_STORAGE_NORMAL
  );
  return $styles;
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Same thing.  I get the error: "Notice: Undefined index: height in image_resize_dimensions() (line 103 of /var/www/mymodule/modules/image/image.effects.inc)".  I add the height param to the scale array, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please, clear cache of your site.

Comment: I've been clearing my cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mymodule_image_default_styles() {
  $styles = array();
  $styles['mymodule_thumb'] = array(
    'label' => 'MyModule Thumbnail',
    'effects' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'image_scale_and_crop',
        'data' => array(
          'width' => 210,
          'height' => 210,
          'upscale' => 1,
        ),
        'weight' => 0,
      )
    ),
    'name' => 'mymodule_thumb',
    'storage' => IMAGE_STORAGE_NORMAL
  );

  return $styles;
}
```

Clear your cache.

Comment: I did clear my cache. I even went into the default/files... styles directories and removed the directories.  I've been clearing my cache, and even running cron.

Comment: Did you add 'upscale' => 1. It is not present in your code, and perhaps your source images are smaller than 210x210?

Comment: @J.Reynolds there is no upscale option for scale and crop effect. It upscales by default so that option is redundant.